# Updating Google App signing certificate break Google Pay

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-pay, android-app-signing

I recently updated my Google App signing certificate (Managed by Google) and it seems to break my Google Pay functionality. I am getting "Request Failed, The merchant is not enabled for Google Pay", as if there is a mismatch in certificate. Upon checking the fingerprint, these fingerprint on the apk matches the Google App signing certificate.

We had Google Pay approved for production already, and when testing apk with my production upload key, the Google Pay still works fine.

So the issue seems only on the live version which uses Google app signing key

I tried reaching out to Google, but we have been waiting for days without answer. Anyone had any experience with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you updated the [Google Pay console](https://pay.google.com/business/console/) with your updated app details? If that doesn't, work, try the support option within the Google Pay console.

Comment: Hi @Soc, I don't see anything that needs changing in the business console. the package id is still the same, I don't see option to put the key or fingerprint there.

Comment: Have you tried contacting support via the Google Pay console?

Comment: yep. still waiting for answer

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I contacted Google Pay support, and they responded by suggesting that I submit my own certificate to the Play Store and use it instead of re-signing the app with the Play Store's certificate. For me, it is not a reasonable solution...