# Google Pay doesn't work when app is re-signed by Google Play with App Signing Key

Tags: android, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, google-pay, android-app-signing

I know this question might be related to [Google Pay Production Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60991254/google-pay-production-environment/60992220) and [Updating Google App signing certificate break Google Pay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62781144/updating-google-app-signing-certificate-break-google-pay), but these issues don't appear to be resolved, and the **Google Pay Support Teams are useless**.

Let me reiterate that Google Pay is **fully functional when the app is signed with the Upload Key in production environment**. It has also been approved in the Google Pay Business Console.

But when the app is uploaded to the Google Play Console, there is an error in the app downloaded from Google Play. In the Console, it can see that the error is `E/Volley: [45] dbl.b: Unexpected response code 500 for https://payments- pa.googleapis.com/payments/apis-secure/ui2/buyflowservice/initialize`.

Upon inspection, this is due to an error that cannot be verified with Google Pay. But as I mentioned above, **the app has already been approved**, so I can fully test Google Pay in production environment.

I'm **pretty sure the issue is entirely due to a *different app signing***, but when consulting Google Pay Support Teams, they didn't mention anything, just kept repeating that the app was approved.

Since the App Signing Key in the Play Console cannot be cancelled once enabled, **I can't completely prevent the Play Console from re-signing my app**. There is also **no way in the Google Pay Business Console to set up app signing**, which is very annoying to me.

I don't know anyone have any suggestions, other than continuing to contact the Google Pay Support Teams?

Comment: On one of the threads you link to, someone mentions they solved it by contacting the Google pay team. Worth the try, and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Do you have any news about the issue? Have you resolved it? Same issue in the project and we have no idea how to repair GPay. Thanks in advance.